# Google Developer Console click Enable API gives "Failed to Load" error

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting an error in Google Developer console under the API Manager when I click on "Overview".  The error is "Failed to Load".

Comment: I think they are updating something. Try to create a `new project` in Google developer console and try to refresh it. Or try to add another account.

Comment: @bjiang: already did that. The same thing... I've sent them a feedback that they have an issue.

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to help.  I really don't what to start over with a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 42.0 worked. Chrome and Internet Explorer displayed "Failed to load" and would not show any listings under the title "Overview."